# odoo duplicated create/export buttons in wizard

Tags: javascript, odoo

In odoo v15 I created a wizard  :

```
odoo.define('slnee_appointment_core.tree_button', function (require) {
"use strict";
 var ListController = require('web.ListController');
 var ListView = require('web.ListView');
 var viewRegistry = require('web.view_registry');
 var utils = require('web.utils');
 var rpc = require('web.rpc');
 var TreeButton = ListController.extend({
   buttons_template: 'slnee_appointment_core.buttons',
   events: _.extend({}, ListController.prototype.events, {
   'click .open_wizard_action': '_OpenWizard',
 }),

 init: function (parent, context) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('this *********************' ,this);
        this.reload();
    },

 _OpenWizard: function () {
   var self = this;
   var selected_lines = self.getSelectedIds();
    return this._rpc({
            'model': 'appointment.reservation.pack',
            'method': 'add_services_to_batch',
            'args': [[], selected_lines],
        }).then(function(result){
                location.reload()
            });
 }
 });
    var SaleOrderListView = ListView.extend({
   config: _.extend({}, ListView.prototype.config, {
   Controller: TreeButton,
 }),
  });
   viewRegistry.add('button_in_tree', SaleOrderListView);
  });
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
<t t-extend="ListView.buttons" t-name="slnee_appointment_core.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="replace">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary open_wizard_action">
            Confirm
        </button>
    </t>
    
</t>
</templates>
```

When the wizard opens at the first time I got **duplicated confirm and export all buttons**.
**The buttons on bottom are not clickable** and they disappear when I remove the group by or apply a filter and they never come back !!

I want to remove them from the beginning, what's is actually happened when I remove the group by or apply a filter, something is refreshed ? is it the controller ?

how can I force this refresh on init ?

Sorry but I am a beginner on odoo development.

[image]

I tried :
self.reload on init
but it did not work

I tried to console log the **this**:

https://imgur.com/TfphdkD

\\ UPDATE ///
I found these two codes but they keep refreshing every 1 second:

```
odoo.define('slnee_appointment_core.AbstractView', function (require) {
"use strict";

require('web.AbstractView').include({

    init: function () {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);

        var self = this;
        if (this.arch.attrs.class) {
            var classList = this.arch.attrs.class.split(' ');
            classList.forEach(function (className) {
                self._checkRefreshClass(className);
            });
        }
    },

    // This method checks if the class name matches the format
    // "crnd-refresh-every-XT", where "X" is an integer,
    // time interval (numbers 0-9)
    // and "T" is time dimensions ("s" - seconds, "m" - minutes).
    // And then compute the value in milliseconds, which is passed to the
    // controller parameters
    _checkRefreshClass: function (className) {
        var refreshClass = 'crnd-refresh-every-';
        if (className.includes(refreshClass)) {
            var time = className.substring(refreshClass.length);
            var interval = time.slice(0, -1);
            var dimension = time.slice(-1);
            if ((dimension === 's' || dimension === 'm') &&
                (/^\d+$/).test(interval)) {
                var dCoefficient = 1;
                if (dimension === 'm') {
                    dCoefficient = 60;
                }
                this.controllerParams.crndViewRefreshInterval =
                    parseInt(interval, 10) * dCoefficient * 1000;
            }
        }
    },
});
});
```

second:

```
odoo.define('slnee_appointment_core.AbstractController', function (require) {
"use strict";

require('web.AbstractController').include({

    init: function (parent, model, renderer, params) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        if (params.crndViewRefreshInterval) {
            this.crndViewRefreshInterval = params.crndViewRefreshInterval;
        }
    },

    start: function () {
        if (this.crndViewRefreshInterval) {
            this._setCRnDRefreshViewTimer();
        }
        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    update: function (params, options) {
        var reload = options && 'reload' in options
            ? options.reload : true;
        if (this._crndViewRefreshTimer && reload) {
            this._setCRnDRefreshViewTimer(true);
        }

        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    _setCRnDRefreshViewTimer: function (cancelPrevTimer) {
        if (cancelPrevTimer) {
            clearTimeout(this._crndViewRefreshTimer);
        }
        this._crndViewRefreshTimer = setTimeout(this.reload.bind(this),
            this.crndViewRefreshInterval);
    },
});
});
```

use:

```
    <record id="appointment_reservation_pack_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">appointment.reservation.pack.tree</field>
    <field name="model">appointment.reservation.pack</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree create="1" delete="0" expand="1"
              js_class="button_in_tree" class="crnd-refresh-every-1s">
            <field name="service_id"/>
            <field name="group_id"/>
            <field name="batch_id"/>
        </tree>
     <!--            <footer></footer>-->
    </field>
     </record>
```

Can anyone suggest an edit to make them work only 1 time ( refresh the view once )

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a matter of refresh.

It's a matter of the way you have built your wizard solution using a mix between JS extensions and XML views.

Perhaps you have created a bigger thing to solve something that could be solved more easily using other approaches but I think everything depends on your initial requirement.

This solution could be a good exercise for you to play with several things around Odoo development but I visualize several simpler way of get the same done